# After Hob (Kid) lost his laboratory and his chemist, how is he planning on creating the drugs?

Tags: robocop-2

In the movie Robocop 2, Hob (the kid) offers the governor of Detroit 50 million in exchange for his uninvolvement in their drug sales. Their laboratory and their chemist perish in an explosion earlier.

So my question is, after they lost their laboratory and their chemist, how are they planning on creating the drugs?

Comment: In the USA only the chief executives of states are titled governors, and the chief executives of cities are usually titled mayors.  The cast list of Robocop 2 lists Willard Pugh as "Mayor Kuzak".  https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0100502/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If Hobb has $ 50,000,000.00 available as bribe money, presumably he also has millions available to spend on setting up a new laboratory and hiring a new dishonest chemist.  And maybe he is already actively looking for chemists to recruit or having the gang's official recruiter, if any, do it.